# R split access columns

Tags: r

I have this sample data in stats_sample.csv:

```
IP,Timestamp,statistic
IP1,20150215204928,1.100000
IP2,20150215204935,1.300000
IP1,20150215204936,0.200000
IP3,20150215204938,2.900000
IP1,20150215204942,1.800000
IP1,20150215204949,1.600000
IP4,20150215204949,2.700000
IP2,20150215204949,1.100000
IP2,20150215204951,3.000000
IP1,20150215204952,1.600000
IP3,20150215204958,0.600000
IP4,20150215204959,0.000000
```

I want to create a plot where I would have for each IP a line - x would be the timestamp and y the statistic. Here is my R script:

```
data <- read.csv("stats_sample.csv", sep=",", head=TRUE)
data <- split(data, data$IP)

png("plot.png")
plot.new()
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
   lines(data[i]$Timestamp, data[i]$statistic)
}
dev.off()
```

As result I get an empty plot.

When I print data[1] I get this:

```
$IP1
    IP    Timestamp statistic
1  IP1 2.015022e+13       1.1
3  IP1 2.015022e+13       0.2
5  IP1 2.015022e+13       1.8
6  IP1 2.015022e+13       1.6
10 IP1 2.015022e+13       1.6
```

How would I make this work please?

Thanks for any efforts.

P.S: My R skills are rather bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert your numeric `Timestamp` to a datetime format first, then initiate a plot using `plot` before using multiple `lines`:

```
data$Timestamp <-   as.POSIXct(as.character(data$Timestamp), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
png("plot.png")
with(data, { 
  plot(0, xlim = range(Timestamp), ylim = range(statistic), xaxt = "n")
  axis(1, at = pretty(Timestamp), labels = pretty(Timestamp))
})
invisible(lapply(split(data, data$IP), function(dat) {
  with(data, lines(Timestamp, statistic, col = IP))
}))
dev.off()
```

Alternatively, you can have it easier using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggsave(filename = "plot.png", 
  ggplot(data, aes(x = Timestamp, y = statistic, colour = IP)) + 
    geom_line()
)
```